# HTACCESS: Redirect to home page if invalid number in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using APACHE server and I want to redirect the url to home page if third parameter is invalid number.
Code I have written is ::

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/app/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ /
```

But its not working.
In short:

www.xyz/app/test/3434 :: should pass

www.xyz/app/test/best :: should fail

www.xyz/app/test/34kkk34 :: should fail

Comment: Something like that is probably what you are looking for: `^/?app/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$` For a more precise guess from our side you have to specify _precise_ acceptance rules in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to redirect when the last part is *not* a number. Stated otherwise, redirect when there's a non digit somewhere. To get this, you must first match any character including digits.

```
^/app/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[a-zA-Z_-][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/?$
```

Since you don't use any parts of the request in the target URL, there's also no need to capture anything `()`.

If you don't care about the particular characters, you can simplify the regular expression and just use `.*` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*`, e.g.

```
^/app/.+?/.*?[^0-9].*/?$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/app/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/[a-zA-Z_-]+/[0-9]+/?$ /
```